# Create Application bar dynamically

Tags: cross-platform, windows-phone-8, application-bar

I want to create `Application Bar dynamically in Windows Phone 8`. I have used the following code to create application bar in appbar.cs file

```
class AppBar
    {
    public AppBar()
    {
        ApplicationBar appbar;
            this.appbar = new ApplicationBar();
            this.appbar.IsVisible = true;
            this.appbar.Opacity = 1;
            this.appbar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
            ApplicationBarIconButton appButon = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
            appButon.IconUri = new Uri("/images/show.png", UriKind.Relative);
            appButon.Text = "Show";
            this.appbar.Buttons.Add(appButon);
            appButon.Click += appButon_Click;

        }
     }

        void appButon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
}
```

If i have created the **instance of AppBar class**, then all the methods called but i unable to see the application bar. I have given `request to create the appbar from webview`. From the javainterface i have created the instance of application bar with the given text and icon. How to show this in the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the my Application bar issue. `Added my application bar with parent element(PhoneApplicationPage)`.

```
class AppBar
    {
    public AppBar()
    {
        ApplicationBar appbar;
        PhoneApplicationPage parentpage = (Application.Current.RootVisual as ContentControl).Content as PhoneApplicationPage; 
            parentpage.ApplicationBar =  new ApplicationBar();         
            appbar = parentpage.ApplicationBar;
            appbar.IsVisible = true;
            appbar.Opacity = 1;
            appbar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
            ApplicationBarIconButton appButon = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
            appButon.IconUri = new Uri("/images/show.png", UriKind.Relative);
            appButon.Text = "Show";
            appbar.Buttons.Add(appButon);
            appButon.Click += appButon_Click;

        }
     }

        void appButon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
}
```