# Create Application bar when request from WebView in Windows phone 8

Tags: cross-platform, windows-phone-8, application-bar

I want to create application with webbrowser. When the request like "**createappbar**" through script, then i have to `create the application bar from JavaInterface methods`. is there any tutorial available. ***I have searched more on the google. But every sample showing the application bar creation from PhoneApplicationPage***. Please suggest me any link or sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem and posted the solution in the below link

[Create Application bar dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381752/create-application-bar-dynamically)